# Proving $ e^2 = e$?

Tags: logarithms, infinite-product

Given the function, $$ f(x)= \frac{1}{e^x-1} \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{x^n}{n!} $$

Then applying the log,

$$ \ln(f(x)) = \frac{1}{e^x-1} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{x^n}{n!} =  \frac{e^x-1}{e^x-1} = 1 $$

$$ \rightarrow \quad f(x) = e \quad \rightarrow \quad  \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!} =e(e^x-1) $$

$$ $$

For $x=1$ we get,

$$ \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{n!} = \frac{1}{1!} \cdot \frac{1}{2!} \cdot \frac{1}{3!} \cdot ...\frac{1}{n!}  \rightarrow 0$$

Which means,
$$ e(e-1)=0 \quad  \rightarrow  \quad e^2=e$$

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Your $f(x)$ is $0$ (the factors tend to $0$), and you applied $\ln$ rather incorrectly. It would be $$
\ln f(x) =  - \ln (e^x  - 1) + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\ln \left( {\frac{{x^n }}{{n!}}} \right)} .
$$

Answer (score 3):

You cannot take the natural log of $0$.

Answer (score 2):

You take the logarithm of the function $f(x)$ which is everywhere equal to $0$ except for $x=0$ where it is undefined. Also, note that for $a= \frac{1}{e^x-1}$ and $b_n = \frac{x^n}{n!}$

$$
\log \left(a \prod b_n\right) = \log(a) + \sum \log(b_n) \not= a \cdot \sum b_n.
$$

Comment: If you look carfully, the OP claims that the result after $\log$ is $a\cdot \sum b_n$.

Comment: Indeed, that makes it even worse :) fixed.

Comment: Now it is correct, except $log$ should be $\log$.

Comment: @Gary What's the difference except the font?

Comment: @EB97 It looks better, moreover Kolja used $\log$ correctly for some of the logarithms. It was just not consistent throughout.